# Proof about the quotient remainder theorem by indirect proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose that every integer can be written in the form $6k+r$ where k is an integer and r is one of the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5.

a) Show that if $p=6k+r$ is a prime different from 2 and 3, then $r=1$ or $5$
d) Show that there are infinitely many primes of the form $6k-1$

Approach:
a) I would consider the cases when $r=0,2,3,4$ and I would find a k such that $gcd(k,r)=1$ then I wouldn't get a prime number which would be a contradiction

d)I don't know how to do this problem. Reading the book, I think I have to this by contradiction like assuming  that the number of primes is finite and can be represented in the form $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ then I would say something like let N  be the integer $p_1*p_2*.....*p_n+1$ and use the assertion which states that N is divisible by some prime different from any of the primes $p1,...,p_n$. Can somebody explain that assertion?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* For (d), argue that $6p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n-1$ has a prime factor of the form $6k-1$.

Indeed, let $p$ be a prime factor of $6p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n-1$. It cannot be $2$, $3$, or any of the $p_i$, because otherwise $p$ would divide $1$. Therefore, $p$ is of the form $6k\pm1$. But the product of primes of the form $6k+1$ is of the same form. Thus, $6p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n-1$ must have a prime factor of the form $6k-1$. As we have seen, this prime cannot be  any of the $p_i$.

Comment: right,  but I still have my inquiries. Intuitively $6p_1p_2..p_n-1$ is not any of the primes $p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n$. I know it's silly but it bothers me.

Comment: @TheMathNoob You are right in that $6p_1p_2 ... p_n-1$ is not divisible by any of the $p_i$. However, $p$ is a different prime altogether because it represents a prime divisor of that number. $p$ is not in the sequence $p_i$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You could also use, e.g., $(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)^2-2$ or $(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)^2+4$.

Answer (score 0):

a) Your strategy of guessing and checking $r=0,2,3,4$ works.

If $r=0$, then $p=6k$, so $6 \mid p$.
If $r=2$ or $r=4$, then $p=6k+2$ or $p=6k+4$. In either case, we can factor out a $2$ from the right side, so $2 \mid p$.
If $r=3$, then $p=6k+3=3(2k+1)$, so $3 \mid p$.

d) Use [@lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834009/307483)'s hint and the fact that $6k-1$ can not be divisible by either $2$ or $3$. Also, use the fact that $6k+5=6(k+1)-1$, so by a), primes are either in the form $6k+1$ or $6k-1$.

Comment: what is an odd composite integer?

Comment: @TheMathNoob An odd composite integer is a composite integer that is not divisible by $2$, such as $3\cdot 7=21$ or $5 \cdot 11=55$. However, I don't see how this applies to here.